# Charts implementation in Ionic2 framework

Tags: ionic-framework, charts, ionic2

What's the easiest way to implement responsive charts (preferably pie chart) in Ionic2 framework?

Comment: nvd3, d3, amcharts, and may more.

Comment: @MMK Could you please share a tutorial? Being newbie at this, I only managed to find tutorials for ionic v1 and Angular.

Answer (score 1):

If you still looking for an answer, I have created a sample ionic 2 project with ChartJs 2.0 and displayed a pie chart in the home page.

You need to include the chartjs.bundle.js file inside your **index.html** file as

`<script src="assets/libs/Chart.bundle.js"></script>`

and then in **home.html**

render the chart as

```
<chart [labels]="labels" [data]="data" type="bar"></chart>
```

and in **home.ts**

```
...    
import { Chart } from 'ng2-chartjs2';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  labels: string[] = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"];
  data: Chart.Dataset[] = [
    {
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ];
}
```

If you need a fully compiled working project source code for reference, get it from my [repo here](https://github.com/darthranjith/Ionic2-Chart)

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Glad, it helped. Cheers :)